# Kompozer Installation step by step

Tags: software-installation

I have extracted the files to a carpet. What's next?. I don't see any executable or shell script to execute the program on ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the file ?

Comment: How can we install from a download source. (Without internet connection)

Answer (score 6):

To Install Kompozer, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libidl0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

**For 32 bit systems:**

```
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i kompozer*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**For 64 bit systems:**

```
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i kompozer*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

<sup>Source:[Install Kompozer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallKompozer)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

On 18.04 64 bit got:
Package libidl0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libidl-2-0:i386 libidl-2-0

Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libidl0' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake. I unintentionally posted my Comment as an Answer. I'll now post it correctly.

Comment: On 18.04 64 bit got: Package libidl0 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: libidl-2-0:i386 libidl-2-0

Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libidl0' has no installation candidate E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate