# unable to install Kompozer on Ubuntu 18.04.1---and now Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: kompozer

At the suggestion of a kind person answering my question I followed the suggestion of going to the following:  Here are the **title, link and and the terminal output**.  Still unable to install Kompozer.  The Software Updater was run and it reported that the software was up to date.

**Kompozer Installation step by step**

[Kompozer Installation step by step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376986/kompozer-installation-step-by-step)

This was the first line of the code entry and the reply:  and it shows the file is already fully retrieved, nothing to do:  This was repeated after entering the next lines of code:  The errors come later, please look.

```
    computer@computer-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:~$computer@computer-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:~$ wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
--2018-10-03 07:31:10--https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
Resolving launchpad.net (launchpad.net)... 91.189.89.222, 91.189.89.223
Connecting to launchpad.net (launchpad.net)|91.189.89.222|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/102977236/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb [following]
--2018-10-03 07:31:11--  https://launchpadlibrarian.net/102977236/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
Resolving launchpadlibrarian.net (launchpadlibrarian.net)... 91.189.89.229, 91.189.89.228
Connecting to launchpadlibrarian.net (launchpadlibrarian.net)|91.189.89.229|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.
```

The last two code entries reported error, here is one of them.

```
computer@computer-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:~$ sudo dpkg -i kompozer*.deb
dpkg: error processing archive kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
(Reading database ... 213540 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking kompozer-data (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) over (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package kompozer-dev.
Preparing to unpack kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking kompozer-dev (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up kompozer-data (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kompozer-dev: kompozer-dev depends on kompozer (>= 1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2).dpkg: error processing package kompozer-dev (--install):dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...Errors were encountered while processing:kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb kompozer-dev
```

I would appreciate help:  All I know is to follow the examples that I can find here.  Thank You (October 3, 2016)

**Listed below are the previous attempts to install KompoZer.  The newest attempt of Oct 3, 2018 is listed above.**
Trying to install KompoZer on 18.04.1 and 16.04.4 following suggestions from askUbuntu:  First downloaded and extracted kompozer-0.8b3.lt.gcc4-2-686.tar.gz. from SourceForge. Now needed to know how to install the extracted files.  Here are:
**Link Question Answer and the Unsucessful terminal output** On how to install kompozer on ubuntu after downloading
[How to install kompozer on xubuntu after downloading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736882/how-to-install-kompozer-on-xubuntu-after-downloading)
1 Answer  If you googled, you would have got this in first place. Any way here you go.

```
    sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1   libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0  libidl0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib
```

And the unsucessful terminal output:

```
[sudo] password for computer: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libidl0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:  libidl-2-0
Package zlib1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libidl0' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'zlib1' has no installation candidate
```

Here is another trial with askUbuntu: **Link, Question, Answer and Unsuccessful terminal output**

[Unable to install Kompozer in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832913/unable-to-install-kompozer-in-ubuntu-16-04)
For briefity only the last lines of code shown, no errors returned on previous lines, but the last four lines gave errors and for briefity just one of them will be shown, more can be given
64-Bit:

```
sudo dpkg -i libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

**The terminal input/output**
entering the first sudo command these errors are encountered

```
sudo dpkg -i libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb 
dpkg: error processing archive libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb (--install):
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb
```

And to be sure this is a 64 bit program and a 64 bit machine:  I would appreciate any help.  Thank you

---

Thank you: I have poured over the link although I can't see how to use its content: Listed are every command I see.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
foo@foo:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
sudo aptitude install <packagename>
sudo aptitude -f install <packagename>
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I want to assured you I have looked at every line:  3rd through 5th are unfamilar to me and I don't understand how they may fix a broken package.
Thank you

Comment: Please, for your own interest, make an effort to explain and format your questions nicely, so that people can understand and answer you more easily

Comment: The input and the output you included in your question are clearly not connected, please re-read the posts where you have seen those answers, specially https://askubuntu.com/questions/376986/kompozer-installation-step-by-step

Comment: Here they are:  And as I said, please see that I feel my inputs are related to the output:  If you can guide me further, please do so.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you tried to run an incorrect  command that looks like this:

```
sudo apt install libx Unable to install Kompozer in Ubuntu 3 11-6
```

Instead of running a command that looks like this:

```
sudo apt install libx11-6
```

Somehow or another you accidentally pasted the string `Unable to install Kompozer in Ubuntu 3` in the middle of the command, so let's start over from the beginning and run the following commands in Ubuntu 18.04. For Ubuntu 16.04 go back to the same link that you mentioned in your question, and follow the instructions for installing KompoZer in 16.04 instead of 18.04.

```
sudo apt install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g  
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb  
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install ./libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo apt install ./kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Note that first you need to download libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb with `wget` before you can install it with `sudo apt-get install ./package.deb`

To start KompoZer, open the terminal and run `kompozer`.

---

#### Update

kompozer is a native snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. This snap package preserves the last available version of KompoZer from 2010, and allows KompoZer to be used on modern operating systems. KompoZer can be installed from the Software app or from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo snap install kompozer
```

Comment: I am new to this, so I interpreted the command you suggested to download as  "wget libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb"                         and that gave me
--2018-10-01 15:45:01--  http://libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb/
Resolving libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb (libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb’

Comment: That's wrong. Ther correct command is `wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb` **Make sure that each command is pasted correctly before you run it.** The links to download the 4 files that should be downloaded by `wget` are all live and all 4 links work.

Comment: I have done that,  Thank you.  I have looked for a start icon in "show applications" and on the left hand tool bar.  I have searched for kompozer.  I will try it again.  Again Thanks

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
To my best I copied your corrected code line and then the 9 lines of code:  I have the 64 bit Bionic Beaver 18.04.1 installed on an HP 8200, which is 64 bit.  but I see errors that make me question the computer or the software package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
This error shows up in a few of the returns from the entry of a line of code.

Comment: @Sunclock2018 I found an error in the last command which I fixed so it should work now.

Comment: When I tried it again, when the second sudo was enter, this was part of what was returned                                                      The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libidl0:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.14) but it is   not installable
       Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not installable
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Your package management is broken because you can't update libc6. If you try to update libc6 it might break tons of other stuff. Nonetheless I will provide you with a link [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/) but continuing to fuss with your package management could easily make it worse in its current degraded condition, and then you will have to backup your data and reinstall the entire OS. Alternatively if you have Synaptic installed, simply open Synaptic and select *Edit* -> *Fix broken packages*.

Comment: Thanks karel I followed your commands and it installed perfectly on ubuntu 18.04